# Covering space Hausdorff implies base space Hausdorff

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

There is an exercise problem in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book asking to show that if $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ is a covering space with $p^{-1}(x)$ finite and nonempty for all $x\in X$, then $\tilde{X}$ is compact Hausdorff iff $X$ is compact Hausdorff.

I've managed to show each part of the statement except for $\tilde{X}$ Hausdorff $\Rightarrow X$ Hausdorff. The problem I encountered was that taking $x\neq y$ in $X$ and $\tilde{U},\tilde{V}$ disjoint open sets in $\tilde{X}$ with $p^{-1}(x)\subset\tilde{U}$ and $p^{-1}(y)\subset \tilde{V}$ (I'm using the assumption that $\tilde{X}$ is compact Hausdorff, thus normal), I could not use these to get disjoint open sets in $X$ separating $x,y$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take distinct $y_1 \neq y_2$ in $X$. Then $F_1 = f^{-1}[\{y_1\}]$ and $F_2 = f^{-1}[\{y_2\}]$ are disjoint, finite and non-empty subsets of $\tilde{X}$. By Hausdorffness we can find disjoint open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ around $F_1$ and $F_2$. Let $O_1$ be an evenly covered neighbourhood of $y_1$, and $O_2$ one of $y_2$.

Now, $f^{-1}[O_1] = \cup_{i=1}^k V_i$, where the $V_i$ are disjoint and open and $f|V_i$ is a homeomorphism between $V_i$ and $O_1$ for all $i$; define $V'_i = V_i \cap U_1$, and define $O'_1 = \cap_{i=1}^k f[V'_i]$, which is open, as a finite intersection of open sets.

Similarly we define $W'_i$ from the inverse image of $O_2$ and $U_2$, and the intersection of their images is called $O'_2$.

These $O'_1$ and $O'_2$ are the required disjoint open neighbourhoods as can be easily checked.

Comment: Could you add the proof that $O_1'$ and $O_2'$ are indeed disjoint?

Comment: For those who might be wondering: $O'_{1}$ and $O'_{2}$ are disjoint because $f^{-1}[O'_{1}]$ and $f^{-1}[O'_{2}]$ are contained in $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ respectively, so any point in the intersection of $O'_{1}$ and $O'_{2}$ would be contained in $U_{1} \cap U_{2}$, which is empty.

Comment: @AlexWertheim It's intriguing that you seem to suggest that showing $\cap_{i=1}^{k}f^{-1}(f(V_{i}'))\subset U_{1}$ is straightforward; checking this is the non trivial part of the problem.

Comment: @AritroPathak: I don't know if I'd call it *the* nontrivial part of the problem. Regardless, when I was solving this problem, the observation I make in my comment was the insight I needed to show that $O_{1}'$ and $O_{2}'$ are disjoint. My comment does not claim to be a complete answer or solution to this point, and indeed, there are a few (mostly set-theoretic) justifications which remain. Whether they are straightforward or not is a matter of opinion, but I don't really think my prior comment makes any claim either way.

Comment: I think one wants to add an argument about counting fiber cardinality in showing that $O_1'$ and $O_2'$ are disjoint. If $x \in O_1' \cap O_2'$, then $f^{-1}(x)$ consists of points from preimages of both $f^{-1}(O_1)$ and $f^{-1}(O_2)$, but since cardinality of two fibers from a single evenly covered neighborhood must be equal, this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

A space $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal is closed in $X \times X$. Now suppose $\tilde X$ is Hausdorff, so the diagonal $\Delta_{\tilde X}$ is closed in $\tilde X \times \tilde X$. Remark that $p \times p : \tilde X \times \tilde X \to X \times X$ is again a finite covering map, hence it is a closed map; and the surjectivity of $p$ implies that $(p\times p) (\Delta_{\tilde X}) = \Delta_{X}$, so $\Delta_X$ is closed in $X \times X$ and therefore $X$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3):

Take $x \neq y$ in $X$ and choose $x' \in \tilde X$ mapping to $x$.  Choose a neighborhood $U'$ of $x'$ and neighborhoods $V_{y'}$ for each $y' \in p^{-1}(y)$ such that none of these neighborhoods intersect.  Let $U$ be the image of $U'$ in $X$.  Define $V$ by pushing the $V_{y'}$ to $X$ first and *then* intersecting.

Show that $U$ and $V$ are neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ that don't intersect.

**Edit:**  Oops, forgot to say you'll want to choose the $V_{y'}$ so that no two intersect.  I've edited my answer above to reflect this.  You can do this by proving the following little lemma (if you don't already know it) and applying it to $\{x'\} \cup p^{-1}(x)$.

**Lemma:** *Let $Y$ be Hausdorff and $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ a set of finitely many* distinct *points in $Y$.  Then there exist neighborhoods $V_i$ of $v_i$ such that no two of the $V_i$ intersect.*

Comment: I can't see what goes wrong if they do intersect.

Comment: Do you know that the cardinality of the fibers of a covering map is constant?  First see my edit above.  Then Choose $v$ in the intersection.  Show that there is one preimage of $v$ in each $V_{y'}$ and that consequently these are all the preimages of $v$.  But $v$ is in $U$ so $v$ must have a preimage in $U'$.

Comment: The cardinality of fibers is constant if Y is connected, isn't?

Comment: @Jim Why is it that "consequently, these are all the preimages of $v$"?

Answer (score 0):

For $x\neq y$ in $X$, we have evenly covered neighbourhoods $U_{x}, U_{y} $ of $x,y$ respectively, and if these neighborhoods are disjoint, we are done. If both $x,y$ are in some same evenly covered neighborhood $U \subset X$, then also, we are done, as this neighborhood is the homeomorphic image of an open set of the covering space $X^{'}$ that is Hausdorff.

So, we assume $U_{x},U_{y}$ are intersecting, with $x$ and $y$ both not in one of them. The basic property of covering spaces then implies that $x,y$ both have an equal number, $n$ (say), of preimages. Further, every element of $U_{x} \cup U_{y}$ has the same number $n$, of preimages in $X^{'}$.

Let the preimages of $x$ in $X^{'}$ be labelled $x_{1},..,x_{n}$, and those of $y$ be labelled $y_{1},..y_{n}$. With the procedure of the previous answer, you can choose neighborhoods in $X'$ around each of these $2n$ points so that each of these neighborhoods are disjoint from another, and all of them get mapped homeomorphically to $U_{x} \cup U_{y}$ by the covering map.

Choose any $(n+1)$ neighborhoods of these $2n$ neighborhoods. Then at least one of them has to contain a preimage of $x$, and at least one of them has to contain a preimage of $y$. Of the (n+1) neighbourhoods chosen, collect all of them containing a preimage of $x$, push to $X$, and then intersect. Call this set $V_{x}$. Choose the remaining, which are neighbourhoods of preimages of $y$,  push to $X$, and intersect. Call this $V_{y}$.

If we have  $a\in V_{x}\cap V_{y} \subset U_{x}\cup U_{y}$ , then $a$ has to have $(n+1)$ preimages in $X'$ which is a contradiction.